# Help Writing a PDF for a Math Course

Tags: soft-question

I have to write up notes on a math course and would absolutely love to make my notes look very similar to this:

[image]

Using libreoffice, with [texmaths](http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/), does anyone know settings, i.e. text format, page layout etc... etc... I should use? (I'm pretty sure this is a program-independent question, but just in case)

I have no idea how to deal with this stuff, when I use libreoffice it starts in the top left-hand corner and covers the page, that's all I know how to do, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

(I fear only a math person would be able to answer this, hence why it's posted here)

Comment: You will probably get a better response at TeX.SE.

Comment: Take a look at http://writelatex.com/. It's a widely used for editing LaTeX.

Comment: @Rainier van Es would you know how to manipulate writelatex.com into looking like the picture in my post by any chance?

Comment: I don't know what exactly should look like the paper, but LaTeX has a lot of possibilities, so all of it should be possible. For example, you can add packages to the page. For instance, the header can be created with the 'fancyhdr' package. Just search on the internet, and you'll find.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX is probably the way to go in this case, and what will be suggested the most here since Math.SE uses it for questions and answers. Though LaTeX can be a lot to learn all at once, so as an intermediate step I would suggest using LyX. It's a little more user friendly and uses LaTeX to create PDFs.

Comment: He is looking for that particular old-math style...within latex!